# What is the correct way to convert Unicode to emoji?

Tags: javascript, unicode, console, emoji, console.log

I have an array with Unicode data like `var data = ["1F923", "1F603"]` 
How can I convert Unicode to emoji?

If I use `"\u{1F923}"` in console, it returns an emoji, but if I use `"\u{"+ data[0] +"}"`, it returns an error. Can anyone please help me to convert unicode to emoji.

Comment: `String.fromCodePoint`?

Comment: How does it work? @Bergi

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Emoji is a subset of unicode. There is no conversion from unicode to emoji necessary or possible. Just change your array to

```
var data = ["\u{1F923}", "\u{1F603}"]
```

If your input is a hex number, you can use

```
String.fromCodePoint(parseInt ("1F923", 16))
```

In HTML you can also use HTML hex entities

```
"&#x" + "1F923" + ";"
```

Comment: It is not a solution. I have a large JSON file with Unicode, I need to show all the Unicode as emoji in HTML without modifying JSON file.

Comment: I added fromCodePoint. Note that your JSON file does not contain Unicode emojis, it contains the hex values of the code points of the emojis.

Comment: Awesome, `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt ("1F923", 16))` returning an emoji. Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

U can use this javascript function for unicode to emoji

```
    var unicodeToChar = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi, function(match) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
  });
}
```

new version

```
    var emojiToUnicode = function(text) {
    var emojiUnicodes = ''
    var i;
    var matchedText = text.match(regex);
    if (matchedText != null) {
        var unicodes = text.match(regex)
            .map(e => "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(1).toString(16));
        for (i = 0; i < unicodes.length; i++) {
            emojiUnicodes = emojiUnicodes + unicodes[i]
        }
        text = text.replace(regex, '') + emojiUnicodes.replace(/\\"/g, '\"');
    }
    return text;
}
```

> You can find sample regexes by searching the following code snippet on
> Github.
>
> ```
> /(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}
> ```

**If you want to convert unicode to emoji this is the function**

```
    var unicodeToChar = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi, function(match) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const unicode = ["1f47f", "1f601", "1f60b", "1f62c", "1f9d0", "1f47f", "1f600", "1f601", "1f602", "1f603", "1f604", "1f605", "1f606", "1f607", "1f608", "1f609", "1f60a", "1f60b", "1f60c", "1f60d", "1f60e", "1f60f", "1f610", "1f611", "1f612", "1f613", "1f614", "1f615", "1f616", "1f617", "1f618", "1f619", "1f61a", "1f61b", "1f61c", "1f61d", "1f61e", "1f61f", "1f620", "1f621", "1f622", "1f623", "1f624", "1f625", "1f626", "1f627", "1f628", "1f629", "1f62a", "1f62b", "1f62c", "1f62d", "1f62e", "1f62f", "1f630", "1f631", "1f632", "1f633", "1f634", "1f635", "1f636", "1f637", "1f641", "1f642", "1f643", "1f644", "1f910", "1f911", "1f912", "1f913", "1f914", "1f915", "1f917", "1f922", "1f923", "1f924", "1f925", "1f927", "1f928", "1f929", "1f92a", "1f92b", "1f92c", "1f92d", "1f92e", "1f92f", "1f970", "1f973", "1f974", "1f975", "1f976", "1f97a", "2639", "263a"]


unicode.forEach((val) => {
  document.body.innerHTML += String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(val, 16))
});
```

Comment: sir can you tell me how to decode \ud83d\udc4d format?

Comment: @Kapilsoni `JSON.parse('"\\ud83d\\udc4d"')`

Comment: You ask me that, "how to decode string unicode format". If it's not that you ask : `"\ud83d\udc4d" === "" `

Comment: sorry for that..i have convert \ud83d\udc4d to emojis can you tell me how to do?

Comment: Your browser will do automatically